# Why is there stutter when the loop runs the second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I used a callback function to loop this animation and also to avoid the text being displayed instantaneously with a delay before each text display but the animation somehow does not work when looping the second time. Also, can you tell me why text() function runs before the effect is even complete. Is there an easier way to control the order of the events other than nested callback functions? Thanks!

```js
$(function test() {
  $(".display-1").text('Heading').fadeToggle(1500, function() {
    $('.display-1').text('Hey').fadeToggle(1500, test);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Defining an empty h1 to add text to later on with jQuery -->
<h1 class="display-1"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,
The `fadeToggle` function can only either fade out or fade in an element,

so the first call hides it.

then the second changes the text and show the element,

the third call hides it again,

and the fourth shows it and changes it's text,

and the fifth start all over, creating a loop.

```js
$(function test() {
   $(".display-1").text('Heading').fadeToggle(1500, function() {
       $('.display-1').text('Hey').fadeToggle(1500, function(){
           $('.display-1').fadeToggle(1500, function(){
               $('.display-1').text('Heading').fadeToggle(1500, test);
           });
       });
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Defining an empty h1 to add text to later on with jQuery -->
<h1 class="display-1"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification and your time :)